# how to uninstall automatic running Apache2.4 in windows 10

Tags: php, xampp

My `c:/xampp/..` folders are missing. I only see the htdocs and php folders. Then I am going to Control Panel and uninstall `xampp`.
After I am going to C drive and try to delete the `xampp` folder but some of the folders are not deleted e.g. apache, mysql and tmp.

I try again to delete but an error message is displayed: "this action can't be completed because the folder or a file ii it is open in another program close the folder or file and try again." No programs are currently running.

How can I remove the `xampp` folder from C drive, please?

This is the first time I am installing xampp and I am using the xampp control panel (running it as administrator).

Comment: just restart the PC and delete the folder, it will work

Comment: By task manager, do "End Task" of Apache/mysql background Process and then remove folders(apache,mysql,tmp)

Answer (score 0):

Open your task manager, in tab Processes find Apache HTTP Server and End task this, you can delete folder apache. If you can't delete folder mysql you need End task the mysqld.exe. Good luck!
[find Apache HTTP Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35jMO.png)

Answer (score 0):

First run the XAMPP control panel and open the Config tab on the right top corner. Below the Browser options there is list of checkboxes with autostarting services, make sure everything is unchecked, close this tab and if apache or other service is running stop it with the Stop button then close the control panel. Check  Windwows Task Manager for other services related to XAMPP and if there are any - shut them. Then go back to the XAMPP folder and delete it. Also you may restart your PC after that.

> **Note:** read how to [make better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because your question is awful.